# Disable conditionally main action's button in EasyAdmin3

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I know how to display button with a condition but what I would like is to completly disable the main actions if the user has a type of status.
If my user has the status of employee then he can not create or delete other users, else he can.
I've tried to "display if" but if he hacks the url, he can still do the action.

```php
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
      
        return $actions
            //Here I would like to add my condition
            ->disable(Action::DETAIL, Action::EDIT)
            // I tried this but this is not secure, he can hacks the url
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::NEW, fn (Action $action) => $action->setIcon('fa fa-plus')
                ->setLabel('admin.crud.user.button.add_contractor')
                ->displayIf(fn () => $user->getStatus() !== self::EMPLOYEE)
            )
    }
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it differently. I created a private function with my conditions and I called it in the configureActions :

```php
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        $this->disableActions($actions);

        return $actions
            //->disable(Action::DETAIL, Action::EDIT)
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::NEW, fn (Action $action) => $action->setIcon('fa fa-plus')
                ->setLabel('admin.crud.user.button.add_contractor')
            )

            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DELETE, fn (Action $action) => $action->setLabel('admin.crud.user.button.delete_profile')
                ->setIcon('fa fa-times')
            )
            ;
    }

    private function disableActions(Actions $actions): void
    {
        $contractor  = $this->getUser();

        $actions->disable(Action::DETAIL, Action::EDIT);

        if ($contractor->getStatus() === self::EMPLOYEE) {
            $actions->disable(Action::DELETE, Action::NEW);
        }
    }
```